# Magento how to get the new customer information when create the new customer

Tags: magento

i have a question about magento, i want get the new added customer information, when create the new customer,any one know how to do this?Thanks

Comment: Hi MRTY your requirement is not clear.Where you want to show the newly added customer? Or how would you like to get it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to execute some code when customer successfully sign up in your website, you can use below code to check if the registration was successful. Note, this will NOT check if customer was registered from checkout page

```
<events>
  <customer_register_success>
    <observers>
      <namespace_module_customer_register_success>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
      </namespace_module_customer_register_success>
    </observers>
  </customer_register_success>
</events>
```

And in your Observer.php file:

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer {
  public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
      $event = $observer->getEvent();
      $customer = $event->getCustomer();
      $email = $customer->getEmail();
      if($email) {
          //code to handle if customer is successfully registered
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Manoj,thanks for your reply,is there have a way to get customer information when customer register at check out page?